# Create an Azure app (webforms .net asp) and use SigleSignOn on and Windows Server Active Directory (not a WAAD)

Tags: azure, active-directory, single-sign-on

I have a website (azure), that has a login page for the user to insert it's username and password.

Currently, the login is using LDAP to autenticate the user.

Now the client wants to use/activate the single sign on functionality, but using their Windows Server Active Directory (they don't want to use the Azure Active Directory).

Is this possible to do? Whats the best approach?

Answer (score 3):

These are the two options I know:

- You can use [Microsoft Active Directory Federation Services (aka ADFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory_Federation_Services). This is a component that should be installed in your customer infrastructure and talks with the AD, your website will talk WS-Federation with ADFS. Authenticating a user means basically redirecting the user to a ADFS, if the user is in the LAN and is already authenticated to AD, ADFS will login automatically, but if is outside it will prompt user credentials.
- Another approach will be to use a third party authentication broker. [Auth0](http://www.auth0.com) is an authentication broker that you can add from the azure store, you will need to create an AD "Connection", which will require to install an small MSI on your customer infrastructure. For this case it works more or less like ADFS but your application talks OAuth with Auth0 rather than Ws-Federation so in lot of cases it is easier to implement.

**Disclaimer:** I work for Auth0.